# How to stop getting notifications on likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

When people comment on my post/photo/link/whatever, it's nice to get a notification, because they say something and it might be interesting to read or perhaps reply to it. But when people like my post, there is really no extra information there, except an increase in number of likes. The notification is just noise in my opinion. Can I stop notifications for all likes?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't choose how to limit notifications on any post. if you turn off notifications on the post it will stop following  it completely.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would appear to be **no**.

[Facebook Notifications Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications) doesn't offer a way to turn off notifications for "likes". In fact, on Facebook itself, you can't even turn off "Activity that involves you".

> You'll always get notifications about activity that involves you, like when someone tags you in a photo or comments on your post.

Email notifications are the only type of notifications where you can turn off notification for "likes".

Comment: Why do they offer a disabled dropdown here, I wonder. Can it be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off “More Activity About You” radio button in notification preferences.

Facebook added this option in 2019.

[image: Disable facebook "likes" notification]